# HTTP POST How to reproduce this post in postman to angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework

I'm trying to reproduce a post that works on the postman in the angular, however, when I send the header it gives an error, however, I make a request to the same server to obtain the token without adding the header and it works.

[image: teste post in postman]

Try send post in angular and return message:
[image]

**ionic.config.json**

[image]

**environment.base.ts**

[image]

This method get an Token, work fine, look not send header...

```
async getTokenWorkForce(){
    return this.loginWorkForce();
}

    async loginWorkForce(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const username = Environment.username_workforce;
            const password = Environment.password_workforce;

            let formData: FormData = new FormData();

            formData.append('referer', this.apiServiceProvider.URL_OS_ORDEMSERVICO_WF_TOKEN);
            formData.append('username', username);
            formData.append('password', password);
            formData.append('client', 'referer');
            formData.append('f', 'pjson');

            this.http.post(this.apiServiceProvider.URL_OS_ORDEMSERVICO_WF_TOKEN, formData)
                .subscribe((response) => {
                    const json = response.json();
                    this.loggedUserTokenWF = `${json.token}`;
                    resolve(this.loggedUserTokenWF);
                });            
        })
    }
```

This method return error, with header…

```
    public async postWorkForceFindAssigmentOS(nroOS: number, outFields: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const url = this.apiServiceProvider.URL_OS_ORDEMSERVICO_WF_GET_ASSIGNEMENTS;

            const formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('outFields', `${outFields}`);
            formData.append('where', `workorderid='${nroOS}'`);
            formData.append('Units', 'Feet');
            formData.append('returnGeometry', 'pjson');
            formData.append('f', 'false');
            await this.authProvider.getTokenWorkForce();

            let header = new HttpHeaders();

            console.log('Token WF: ' + this.authProvider.loggedUserTokenWF);
            header = header.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authProvider.loggedUserTokenWF}`);

            this.httpServiceProvider
                .postWorkForce(header, url, formData)
                .subscribe(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    resolve(response);
                }, (err) => {
                    LogHelper.logError(err);
                    reject(err)
                });
        });
    }

    postWorkForce(
        headers: HttpHeaders,
        url: string,
        model: any,
        times: number = 3
    ) {
        return this.http.post(
            url,
            model,
            {
                headers: headers
            }
        ).pipe(retry(times));
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a CORS issue?

Comment: @MikeOne iam not dev backend...

Comment: Well, a dev backend needs to modify the backend to enable cors for your front app

Comment: im create proxy in file ionic.config.json and use it!